# Pagination error in Ruby

Tags: ruby, pagination

In my **ror** app I would like to use pagination.

For that I have used a method in my helper

```
def show_pagination_links(base_url, page_key, page_num, list_size, per_page)

html = ""
append_key = (base_url.include?"?") ? ("&" + page_key) : ("?" + page_key)
html += "<a href='" + base_url + append_key + "=" + (page_num - 1).to_s + "'>&laquo; Prev</a> &nbsp; |&nbsp;  " if page_num > 1
html += "<a href='" + base_url + append_key + "=" + (page_num + 1).to_s + "'>Next &raquo;</a>" if list_size >= per_page
html
end
```

In the controller I have used

```
@return_value.paginate(:page => @pageno, :per_page => @per_page, :descending => true)
```

Where `@return_value` is the return value from my db (mysql)

in view

```
<%= show_pagination_links(@my_events_url, 'page', @pageno.to_i, @return_value.size, @per_page).html_safe %>
```

but am getting error as
    undefined method `paginate' for #

I don't know how to solve it ... pls any one help me

Answer (score 1):

Have you included the `will_paginate` gem in your gemfile?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate)